# Unable take input from USART - FreeRTOS - AT32UC3A0512

Tags: avr-gcc, atmel, freertos, uart

Just trying my hands on FreeRTOS. Following are my setup -

1. Micro-controller - AT32UC3A0512
2. Board - EVK1105
3. Using FreeRTOS
4. Environment - AVR Studio 5 with ASF latest 2.3 framework

I just created a new project from Example project FreeRTOS. I am checking the USART currently.
When run the example project, I am able to transmit characters from my development board to PC through USART but when I type or input something on my PC usart terminal program(using Putty), I am not able to see anything. Can anybody suggest what may be wrong? Or do I need to change the code in the current example code to get input and display on my terminal program for USART?

Thanks...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the problem solved. I removed the ISR based code. Just I initialized the gpio module and then initialized the rs_232 mode for usart , rest I used the existing USART.h and usart.c file API to send or receive data in a FreeRTOS task. That solved my problem...

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I'm thinking:

1. Is your putty character ending set right? Like probably utf-8 to send to your MCU?
2. Is your MCU receiving anything in its receive buffer?

Hope it helps (:

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem too. It seemed that the task had an stackoverflow.
It didn't freeze but went into an infinite loop in the applicationstackoverflowhook function.
Giving the task more stack solved the problem.

Comment: thanks for your update. By the way could you please let me kmow procedure for tracing the tasks and their problems like stack-overflow?